# c program to calculate factorial not working

Tags: c, function, parameter-passing

Hi I have to write this program which calculates a factorial of a given number. The first function must read in a number, then pass this to the main function which passes that value to a second function, which calculates the factorial of that number, then passes that factorial to the main.a third function should then be called from the main which displays the factorial Here is what I wrote and I can't get it to work:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int getValue()
    {

        int n;

        printf("Enter number: ");
        scanf("%d%*c", &n);
        return(n);
    }

    int factorial(int n)
   {

        int i, f;

        f = 1;
        for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
        f = f * i;

        return(f);
    }

    void printFactorial(int f)
    {

        printf("The factorial is: %d", f);

        return;
    }

    int main()
    {

        int f = getValue();
        factorial(f);
        printFactorial();

        return(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a parameter for printFactorial().

Try this:

```
printFactorial(factorial(f));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing the calculated factorial value to `printFactorial()`.  Pass the value to the printing function:

```
int main()
{

    int f = getValue();
    int fact = factorial(f);
    printFactorial(fact);
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing value  to printFactorial(). Pass the value to the printing function:
You can store factorial(f) result to some variable and then paas or you can pass factorial(f) to printing function

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the return value of `factorial()` and are not passing the argument to `printFactorial()`. These are the most obvious problems.

Another, most subtle, issue is that `factorial()` will only work for small values of `n`. The factorial function grows so rapidly that you'll quickly encounter integer overflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main()
{

    int f = getValue();
    factorial(f);
    printFactorial(f);
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Could you add some context, to explain the code abit?